# Reading .xpt files Using R in Mac

Tags: r, sas

Cannot read `.xpt` files Using `R` in Mac. I have tried `foreign`, `hmisc`, and `sas7bdat`, none worked.

Errors are mainly

`Error in lookup.xport(file): unable to open file: 'No such file or directory`

OR

`Error in lookup.xport(file) : file not in SAS transfer format`.

Comment: You might try the package `SASxport` and the function `read.xport`

Comment: BTW,  are you _sure_ it is a SAS xport file and not a FireFox xpt file?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I managed to read the file. The problem was that there was a space after the .XPT that caused all that problem. So I needed to type "filename.XPT " instead of "filename.XPT". All is working now.